# MPICH2 unable to exectue mpiexec in Windows 7

Tags: mpi

After installing MPICH2 in Windows 7, I tried mpiexec -n 2 cpi in \MPICH2\examples folder. But I got error message.

```
Fatal protocol error: check version between Mpiexec.exe, Msmpi.dll, and Smpd.exe.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have another mpiexec.exe in one of the folders of the system path. Try specifying full path in front, such as: "C:\Program Files\MPICH2\bin\mpiexec.exe".

Comment: I added full path in system path. But still it gives same error messages. So I tried to find another mpiexec.exe file. And I found out mpiexec.exe file in C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin. Should I remove this?

Comment: You can temporarily rename Microsoft MPI directory. Look at the list of installed services. You need MPICH2 smpd.exe from Argonne National Lab to be in the Started state and any other mpich service should be stopped.

Comment: Thanks now it works. It gives another error after renaming "smpd version mismatch". So I checked it's version by smpd -version. It was "1.0.3" and I solved the problem by smpd.exe -install. Now mpiexec works.

Answer (score 1):

1) In addition you can check the folders using

```
where mpiexec.exe
where smpd.exe
where msmpi.dll
```

2) Also you can uninstall one of your MPI instalation (or reinstall it - sometime it works).

3) Another solution is to link statically.